# I want to show a UIPickerView when i click UIBarButtonItem to select a city [IOS Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

this is my code....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My City +", nil);

SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];


[revealController panGestureRecognizer];
[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];

UIBarButtonItem *centerButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
[centerButtonItem setTarget:self];
[centerButtonItem setAction:@selector(showCitySelector:)];

self.navigationItem.titleView=centerButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"]style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.184 green:0.184 blue:0.988 alpha:1];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
_detailTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.486 green:0.486 blue:0.486 alpha:1];    

UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newspaper18.png"]
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightRevealButtonItem;
```

}

```
-(IBAction)showCitySelector:(UIButton *)sender {
if(_cityPicker.hidden)
    _cityPicker.hidden=NO;
else
    _cityPicker.hidden=YES;
```

}

Ok the problem is this error:
2015-02-19 16:53:43.440 MyCityPlus[1728:251613] -[UIBarButtonItem frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16653460
2015-02-19 16:53:43.446 MyCityPlus[1728:251613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16653460'

Im a newbie, please help me im stuck, i know the problem is when i try to create the button i already try so many options and i have the same error

Comment: It's saying you're trying to access the nonexistent frame property of a UIBarButtonItem object, but I don't see that anywhere in your code... Are you sure the error is caused by these lines?

Comment: Ok what do i need to add, because for the rightRevealButtonItem it works and no need to anything extra, i just try to understand this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem here is the center button - you set the titleView property, which must be a UIView, to your cetnerButtonItem, which is a UIBarButtonItem. As weird as it seems, UIBarButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView. That's why your code is throwing the exception.

Notice that the error will happen only for the center button, not the left or right ones, which are supposed to be UIBarButtonItem.

To fix this, you have a few choices: if you change the type of centerButtonItem to UIButton (which is a subclass of UIView), the code will compile and run, although it may look wonky. Another option would be to remove either the button on the right or the left and put your center button there.